# Missing private key from smart card device [gpg, yubikey]

Tags: encryption, security, gnupg, smartcard

In my work environment, I currently use a smart card yubikey device for signing commits and encryption/decryption tasks. Apparently, some updates caused me some issues so now my computer cannot find the private key from my device.

In fact, whenever I try to export my secret keys:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys
```

I get a message like this: **gpg: WARNING: nothing exported**

Also encrypting/decrypting files has become impossible:

1) encrypting

```
 gpg --encrypt --sign --armor -r piero.borrelli@tanaza.com plain.txt
```

**gpg: no default secret key: No secret key**

**gpg: plain.txt: sign+encrypt failed: No secret key**

2) Decrypting

```
 gpg --decrypt to-decrypt.asc > decrypted.txt
```

**gpg: decryption failed: No secret key**

**Please note**: printing public keys and the command `gpg --card-status` correctly work and print data. Apparently the problem is related to the private key missing. Any idea?